# Why does <Link to="/"> cause an infinite loop/crash in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

i'm currently developing a React+Redux front-end app and i'm running into a problem that seems inexplicable to me. When using a  component, it works correctly from any other page but the homepage (the / route). When clicked on from the homepage, it crashes the app/browser.

I included react-router and react-redux in the tags because I use those libs, I don't know if they actually have any contribution to the cause of the problem.

I have the following setup:

src/index.js

```
...

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Fragment>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/profile" exact={true} component={Profile}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/settings" component={settings}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={loginPage}/>
                    <Route path="/logout" component={logoutPage}/>
                </Switch>
                <Footer/>
            </Fragment>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('mount')
);

...
```

src/layout/footer.js

```
...
                    <div className="col">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/">Privacy</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/">Another Link</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/">Disclaimer</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/">Cookies policy</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
...
export default Footer;
```

src/pages/home.js

```
...

render(){
    var homePage = (
        <Fragment>
            <HeroComp />
            <Explainer />
            <StoreFinder />
            <CalloutComp />
        </Fragment>
    );
    return homePage;
}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Home);
```

Clicking on any of the  components in the Footer should send me to the homepage. Which it does correctly if you are on any page but home. 
But if you are already on the homepage and click on the link I expect it to either do nothing, but it seemingly crashes the app / browser. My best guess is that it somehow starts an infinite loop or memory leak but can't figure out why.

[Edit]
To clarify, there is no actual error. The browsertab just freezes and becomes unresponsive. The only way out is to close the tab.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. There is no actual error. The browser tab just freezes and becomes unresponsive.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error?? Usually, when it's a memory leek or infinit loop, react throw an error

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I tried keeping the inspector open while clicking a link but it just freezes the whole tab. I've never let it run for too long though. I might just try that and see what happens.. maybe React/Firefox will give an error message eventually. Will report back!

**Edit** Turns out firefox just keeps prompting: "A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do? [Stop it] [Wait]". Nothing really happens beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (nobody could've figured this out without more information about the problem..)

After some more research/playing around I was able to find out that the problem was the requestAnimationFrame call in **Map.js**. Turns out, this is a google maps component (using **google-maps-react**) i've created that will initialize a google map element in the **onComponentMount** event.

However, if i'm on a page with the component mounted and try to link to that page from itself (for example, homepage and clicking on the logo or home button), the component tries to mount itself again (without properly destroying the existing google maps instance) and causes an infinite loop.

To "fix" this, I simply added a conditional statement to check if the map has been loaded.

`if(!this.map) ) this.initMap();`

[image: Figuring out what was causing the infinite lag/loop]